# Need help for Group by function

Tags: sql, sum

On below query I want sum of WORK_HOURS Hours per OP_NO, how can i add sum?

---

```
SELECT

  OP_RESULT.EMP_NO,
  EMPLOYEE_NAME,
  OP_RESULT.ACCOUNT_DATE,
  OP_RESULT.WORK_HOURS Hours,
  OP_RESULT.WAGE_GROUP,
  OP_RESULT.ORDER_NO,
  OP_RESULT.OP_NO,
  OP_RESULT.WORK_CENTER_NO


FROM WES.OP_RESULT OP_RESULT,
     WES.COMPANY_PERSON COMPANY_PERSON

WHERE OP_RESULT.EMP_NO = COMPANY_PERSON.EMP_NO

AND (OP_RESULT.ORDER_NO = ?)

ORDER BY OP_RESULT.OP_NO
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally helpful if you can add a sql fiddle with sample data in it. It makes people respond faster. Here is the sql fiddle I created for your problem.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ec3c9/1/0

Your query has to be something like this

```
SELECT
sum(OP_RESULT.WORK_HOURS) as total_hours,
OP_RESULT.OP_NO  
FROM OP_RESULT OP_RESULT,
 COMPANY_PERSON COMPANY_PERSON
WHERE OP_RESULT.EMP_NO = COMPANY_PERSON.EMP_NO
group by OP_RESULT.OP_NO
```